# 'city' option not displayed in shopping cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I am using magento 1.9.2.3.

The problem I am facing is that when I was working in the local machine the `city` option in `Estimate Shipping and Tax` section in shopping cart page was perfectly displayed below 'country' option.

But when I move everything to the server with the same database, the code is there but the `city` option alone is missing.

Is there anything I should activate in the admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in System -> Configuration -> (Customers ->) Customer Configuration in the section "Name and Address Options" if there's anything that might prevent showing the city and if it is set in the "Adress templates" fields.

But my best guess is a CSS-issue where this field maybe set to `display:none`.

A little code would definitely help...